# Уведомление о завершении сборки проекта в Visual Studio(2012)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Часто когда сидишь над большими проектами, <strike>особенно ночью</strike>, на сборку уходит много времени, но еще больше тратится из-за того, что по завершении проекта по уммолчанию отсутствует звуковое уведомление, <strike>**которое может тебя разбудить**</strike>. Как такое уведомление можно настроить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Создать *.bat файл с командой `@echo •`
2. Открыть свойства проекта в Visual Studio, затем Build Events > Post-Build Event > Command Line > Edit
3. Ввести команду call <имя батника> (например call C:\beep.bat)
4. Сохранить изменения и протестить.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь в проект в `Target Name="AfterBuild"` [вызов Sound из msbuildextensionpack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.8.0/html/d5ecc508-4437-dc9d-569d-2eb066a29c81.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Получилось запустить музыку командой (Открыть свойства проекта в Visual Studio, затем Build Events > Post-Build Event > Command Line > Edit
Ввести команду->) C:/путь_до_файла.mp3
Единственно, при ошибке в проекте музыка не воспроизводится